# PHP Cloud Datastore and Cloud Dataflow

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I designed to keep raw data from IoT devices to Cloud DataStore via GAE Flex (PHP). I also want to bring those data to BigQuery via Cloud DataFlow. However, I cannot find the standard or official documents which express the ways to read and dump data among DataStore and DataFlow services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using BigQuery's ability to load Cloud Datastore backups. Essentially just schedule a regular backup into a GCS bucket, then load the backup from GCS into BigQuery. [[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore)].

If you want to use Dataflow, you can use the DatastoreIO source in Java or Python (sorry, no PHP here). [[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/datastore-io)]

Read results from a query into a PCollection:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<Entity> entities = p.apply(
   DatastoreIO.v1().read()
       .withProjectId(projectId)
       .withQuery(myQueryObject));
```

Then write this PCollection to wherever you want the data.